# grab command output launched with start-process

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, dos

I want to run a system command as another user using a powershell script .
My objective is to run whoami command and redirect the output to a file as a first step.
This is the code I'm using :

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "test"-AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("test", $secpasswd)

Start-Process "cmd" -Argument {"whoami > debug.txt"}-Credential $mycreds -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory "c:\"
```

A dos window is created but nothing happens after.
Thanks.

Comment: You miss a `/c` argument for `cmd.exe`, that's why you don't get a thing.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem .

Answer (score 0):

You miss a /c argument for cmd.exe, that's why you don't get a thing.

```
Start-Process "cmd" -Argument {"/c whoami > debug.txt"}-Credential $mycreds -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory "c:\"
```